# Controller with custom base controller not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

### Update

Tried to clarify my problem

---

I have a ASP.NET 5 Web Api application. I'm trying to create a controller class that makes use of a custom base controller. As soon as I add a constructor to the base controller then MVC can no longer find the `Get()` end point defined in the `Generic` class.

***This works:***

When I navigate to `/api/person` then the `Get()` end point is triggered defined in the `Generic` class

Generic:

```
public class Generic
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

PersonController

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PersonController : Generic
{
}
```

---

***This doesn't work***
When I navigate to `/api/person` then the `Get()` end point is *not* triggered. The only thing that is added is a constructor in both the `Generic` class and the `PersonController` class.

```
public class Generic
{
    protected DbContext Context { get; set; }

    public Generic(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

PersonController

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PersonController : Generic
{
    public PersonController(DbContext context) : base(context) { }
}
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "This doesn't work" and "can no longer find"?

Comment: Do you use Dependency Injection ? If you are, can you show registers ?

Comment: Your `CustomBase` must inherit from `Controller`... And if you have that, you should read [ask] and create a [mcve]. Show the exact error you get and the research you did to resolve that error. If you add a parameterless constructor, then the default controller factory indeed cannot instantiate your controllers anymore, and you can solve that  using dependency injection or by introducing your own controller factory. All of this has been covered before, so try searching.

Comment: @CodeCaster That doesn't work. Also, it's ASP.NET 5. You're not required to add the base `Controller` class. But even when I do add it, I still cannot call my `Get()` endpoint. Agian, it does work when I remove the `constructors` from `PersonController` and my `Generic` class

Comment: You're right, I missed that. Anyway the rest of my comment still stands. You must instruct MVC to inject your context into your controller constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with inheriting from another base class. I think the problem is, a proper implementation of your `DbContext` is not being injected to the constructor. Since asp.net 5 is so modular/dependency injectable, you need to explicitly configure it.

In the `ConfigureServices` method in your Startup.cs class, register your `DbContext`  service so MVC will use that and inject that to your class controller when needed.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddDbContext<DbContext>();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```